# Azure Web Apps: FTP-uploaded file permissions

Tags: php, azure, ftp, permissions

I'm in the process of getting a Laravel 5 app working on Azure Web Apps and am encountering an issue via Laravel's temporary storage.

Any time a template renders, Laravel attempts to cache it to the local filesystem.  Unfortunately, for some reason Laravel doesn't have permission to write to its storage directory.

- I am deploying my application from my build server via FTP
- I am running on the free-tier shared infrastructure (just while I'm getting set up)
- My deployment server is running Linux

In this circumstance, it's obvious what the problem is.  Unfortunately, what I don't understand is why my web server doesn't have access to write to the directories my FTP user uploads.

Ideally any solution offered will be one that I can automate as part of my deploy process.

Comment: In which folder does Laravel try to cache the files?

Comment: Laravel has files outside of the `wwwroot` directory, which is fine.  One of the directories is called `storage` and it's in there that Laravel expects to do a bit of static caching of templates & other stuff.

Comment: Using the free-tier the VMs are shared, please, check if the problem happens when running on standard, when a full vm is associated to your hosting plan

Comment: Do free-tier VMs not allow write access to the filesystem from PHP?

Comment: I think it's only to your local app directory, not outside it.

Comment: So, you mean the `wwwroot` directory?

Comment: Here talk about the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964129/can-i-write-to-file-system-on-azure-web-site

Answer (score -1):

According to http://clivern.com/working-with-laravel-caching/, you can change the directory of the cache files using the cache.php configuration file. I'd like to suggest you to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to obtain the root folder of your web app, and then construct a path for the cache files.