# How to log in Azure Webjob with Log4net?

Tags: azure, log4net, azure-webjobs

I have a web project and a console project. I've published my web project on Azure (after having the console app attached as a Azure Webjob to the web project).
Now I want to use Log4net to log in files. It works for the web project but I can't get it to work for the Webjob...

Here is my log4net config :

```
<log4net>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="./_logs/[%date{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}]_webjob.log" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="4096KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%newline %date [%thread] %-5level %logger  - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="myloggername">
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
</logger>
```

[Some guy said it would work with a absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169011/log4net-to-azure-webjob) but it doesn't :

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:/home/site/wwwroot/App_Data/Logs/AccountMaintenance/log4net_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log" />
```

Comment: try `d:\home\logfiles\mylogfile.log`

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following value instead:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="d:\home\logfiles\mylogfile.log" />
```