# localhost works but moving to server breaks file conversion

Tags: c#, .net, iis

So I have a c# project that can convert textbox text into .ePub file (using 3rd party library) to download.

Testing on localhost works fine. The ePub file is created locally inside the project folder then transmitted to the users (browser download).

> (path)\Document_Data\125028197077241091041102140245040098055209043040\testing
>   word goal.epub"

But after uploading the project to a live site that Download feature breaks.

It's hard to debug on a live site but **normally**, does an IIS installation allow for creating files (that temp .ePub file to transmit) in the server's file system from code?

Is a storage solution required? This project used to have an azure storage account but not anymore.

I don't see any other reason why it wouldn't work other not being able to create the file.

My site just shows a blank page. Any tips on how to show actual errors? In web.config I did not set it to not show errors.

Thanks!

Comment: well when you debug this locally what is the path on your local IIS as far as where the file(s) are stored..? the path on your local should match on the target.. do not use hard coded values I would look up how to use the `Server.MapPath` function as well..

Comment: You have to make sure that the file properties are correct.
The user that is used to run the IIS Application Pool must have write access to the directory where you are creating the file.

Comment: It's also a very good idea to try and log all exceptions on the production server (but don't show them to the user :)

This can be done 'manually' by hooking into the exception event in your Global.asax, or by using something like Elmah.

Comment: Probably should check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964129/can-i-write-to-file-system-on-azure-web-site).