# What is the path of an excel file in bot framework?

Tags: .net, azure, botframework

I am working with bot framework and i want to create an excel file in my bot but i don't know how to create the file inside http://yoursuperbot.azurewebsites.net/Files/, so it will be very helpfull if someone help me here.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I write to file system on azure web site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964129/can-i-write-to-file-system-on-azure-web-site)

Answer (score 1):

As your bot scales up, you'll probably want to run it across multiple nodes, in which case storing the doc on a single node doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you just want access to the doc, I'd suggest storing it in blob storage.  There's a good tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs).

One the other hand if you are using the excel file to store data (that you may want to change / update), I'd suggest table storage.  Here's a [tutorial on that.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables)

Once you get past the initial setup (which isn't too hard), you'll find these to be much better solutions.