# ASP.NET Core logging with NLog and MS SQLServer in Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, nlog

I would like to implement NLog in my ASP.NET Core project that is going to be deployed to Azure.

I am using the code suggested in https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreNlog

How do I modify the following lines to allow it to be used in Azure?

In nlog.config:

```
internalLogFile="C:\git\damienbod\AspNetCoreNlog\Logs\internal-nlog.txt"
```

In the Startup class:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["configDir"] = "C:\\git\\damienbod\\AspNetCoreNlog\\Logs";
```

Comment: I found this that looks like it may be what you are looking for https://damienbod.com/2016/08/17/asp-net-core-logging-with-nlog-and-microsoft-sql-server/

Comment: That page also does not say how to modify all references to "C:\git\..." so that it will work in Azure.

Comment: Can you write to file in azure?

Comment: Yes, answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964129/can-i-write-to-file-system-on-azure-web-site I suppose I can use Server.MapPath for the Startup class change. How do I do that in the config file?

Comment: Found the answer. http://intellitect.com/creating-an-nlog-wrapper-that-logs-to-azure-table-storage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this article](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreNlog): **An internal log file is also defined, so that if something is wrong with the logging configuration, you can find out why.** we can know the internal log file is saved on disk via configure `internalLogFile="C:\git\damienbod\AspNetCoreNlog\Logs\internal-nlog.txt`, and based on my test, we can modify it to save internal log file on Azure web app server.

I configure it to:

```
internalLogFile="D:\home\site\AspNetCoreNlog\Logs\internal-nlog.txt"
```

and

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["configDir"] = "D:\\home\\site\\AspNetCoreNlog\\Logs";
```

The app works fine on Azure web app service, and I can access AspNetCoreNlog folder and internal log file via [Kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console).

[image]