# Azure path for readiing/writing static files

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, deployment

I am trying to read/write a file in Azure, which i put into  the `wwwroot\words.txt`-folder

```
        private readonly string _Filename = @"wwwroot\words.txt";
```

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\words.txt'.
>   File name: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\words.txt'

```
  private readonly string _Filename = @"words.txt";
```

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\words.txt'.
>   File name: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\words.txt'

```
  private readonly string _Filename = @"D:\home\site\wwwroot\words.txt";
```

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\words.txt'.
>   File name: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\words.txt'

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117675/azure-and-file-createtext-filenotfoundexception-could-not-find-file)

```
private readonly string _Filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "words.txt");
```

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\words.txt'.
>   File name: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\words.txt'

Locally it works. Is there anything I  miss (,without using a dataabase) ?

Comment: Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to read/write a file in Azure, which i put into the wwwroot\words.txt-folder

To achieve your requirement, you can try the following code snippet.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _env = env;
    }
    public IActionResult ReadTxt()
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "words.txt");

        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(path))
        {
            byte[] content = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Hello World");

            fs.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }

        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

        ViewData["path"] = path;

        ViewData["mes"] = text;

        return View();
    }
```

View page

```
<h1>ReadTxt</h1>

Read file form @ViewData["path"]
<hr />
@ViewData["mes"]
```

Test Result

[image]

Besides, if `words.txt` is stored in [web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows#web-root), as below.

[image]

To access it, you can use `var path = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "words.txt");`.

Comment: Just what I needed. Works perfectly and fast.